# Mass and center of mass of lamina: $B={(x,y);x^2+y^2\le1,0\le y}$? I'm close to the answer but I'm missing something.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'd like some help here because I can't get the right answer. The lamina we are working with is defined by:
$B={(x,y);x^2+y^2\le1,0\le y}$. Also the density function is "proportional to the distance of the point (x,y) to the x-axis"

I think here is where my mistake lies, for me density function is: $p(x,y)=y$

Acording to the exercise center of mass should be: $(Xc=0,Yc=\frac{3pi}{32})$

So I did this:

To find mass M I converted to polar coordinates. $x=rcos(\theta),y=rsin(\theta)$

$M=\int\int_Bp(x,y)dA => M=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^1rsin(\theta)rdrd\theta=2/3$.

Now with the mass we can find $Xc$ and $Yc$. It's easy to note that $Xc=0$ with symmetry

$Yc = \frac{1}{M}\int\int_Byp(x,y)da = > Yc=\frac{3}{2}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1rsin(\theta)rsin(\theta)rdrd\theta=\frac{3\pi}{16}$

But Yc should be $\frac{3\pi}{32}$, so I'm close but I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Your solution looks correct to me.  Is there a mistake in the textbook?

Comment: Well... it would not be the first mistake. This is the second one, worse part is that I rely on these answers since I'm not good at math so I keep hunting what I did wrong for quite some time...

Comment: I checked as well, but I also did not see anything you did incorrectly either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X=0$ by symmetry.

$Y= {\int_0^1 2 y^2 \sqrt{1-y^2}dy \over \int_0^1 2 y \sqrt{1-y^2}dy } = {3 \pi \over 16}$.

Comment: Well looks like the answer in the text was wrong then. Thank you.